# Function returning before array is populated

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display all the documents in a collection from my Firestore database. Here is where I query the DB and turn the documents into usable objects.

```
class DatabaseService {
  static List<Recipe> getSavedRecipes(String uid) {
    List<Recipe> recipes = [];
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('saved recipes')
        .get()
        .then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        print("Successfully completed");
        for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          recipes.add(Recipe.fromFirestore(docSnapshot));
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );
    print(recipes);
    return recipes; //race condition here - for some reason it is returning before the array is populated
  }
}
```

Oddly enough, the function is returning before it is able populate my recipes array, making this print statement

`print(recipes);` return nothing ([])

Is there a reason why this is happening? Any way to fix it?

UPDATE :

Fixed the issue by doing this:

```
class DatabaseService {
  static Future<List<Recipe>> getSavedRecipes(String uid) async {
    late List<Recipe> recipes = [];
    final docs = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('saved recipes')
        .get();

    await docs.then(
      (querySnapshot) {
        print("Successfully completed");
        for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
          recipes.add(Recipe.fromFirestore(docSnapshot));
        }
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error completing: $e"),
    );

    return recipes;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because the method inside `.then()` is called whenever the Future from the `get()` method finishes. This occurs asynchronously and there's nothing in your code that's stopping the code from reaching the `return recipes` statement.

Try converting your code to an asynchronous method. Try the following and let me know if it works (not tested, there may be syntax errors):

```
class DatabaseService {
  static List<Recipe> getSavedRecipes(String uid) async {
    List<Recipe> recipes = [];
    final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('saved recipes')
        .get();

    for (var docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
      recipes.add(Recipe.fromFirestore(docSnapshot));
    }

    print(recipes);
    return recipes; //race condition here - for some reason it is returning before the array is populated
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. When I switch the code to what you have described, I am unable to use querySnapshot in the for-loop. I am unsure of what that variable is referring to/how to recreate the same logic without using .then().

Comment: I have corrected a bug in the code I showed you. You were not able to access `querySnapshot` because it was not defined. Please try in your code and use the analyzer to correct any other missing syntax errors.